# .htaccess redirects with multiple paramenters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am rebuilding a real estate site and we have completely restructured how the database handles the properties and I am now trying to redirect all of the old property urls to the new ones.  The problem that I am having is that the old urls used multiple parameters(including the section and the property id) for a single property and the new urls only use a slug for the property name.

Example:

```
OLD: https://www.example.com/listings.php?sect=1&view=92
NEW: https://www.example.com/listings/tombstone-ranch
```

My current .htaccess looks like the following with the last two lines being the rewrites for converting the slugs into clean urls...all of this works fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteRule ^listings/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /listings/index.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^listings/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ /listings/index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

The Problem that I am having is that neither of the following seems to work:

```
Redirect 301 /listings.php?sect=1&view=92 /listings/tombstone-ranch
```

and neither does this:

```
RewriteRule ^listings.php?sect=3&view=33 /listings/tombstone-ranch
```

or any other variations that I have tried.

Any thoughts? .htaccess is not my strong suit and unfortuinately I need to get these to work considering the old version of the site and it's urls have been around for almost 8 years now so there is the potential for dead links on about 75 properties.

Comment: if the query after index.php doesn't have tombstone-ranch, I don't think that you can do it. Or in last case it might work if you add the properties 1 by 1 on your htaccess which would be painful to do. for example example.com/listings.php?category=tombstone-ranch -> example.com/listings/tombstone-ranch this would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this rule. Can't test it at the moment.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sect=1&view=92
RewriteRule ^listings\.php$ /listings/thombstone-ranch/? [L,R=301]
```

Also the rule you added will not work because you must add a backslash

Wrong:

```
RewriteRule ^listings.php?sect=3&view=33 /listings/tombstone-ranch
```

Right:

```
RewriteRule ^listings\.php?sect=3&view=33 /listings/tombstone-ranch
```

Don't forget since your main URL is a query, you should use the first option that I gave to you. If that doesn't work leave a comment and I'll be glad to help you out